# Javascript Regex to check for String in line with pre and post characters

Tags: jquery

I am writing a regex function so that I can test a string for a few options.

here are some examples of Strings I want to search for.

```
 5.6 - 6.6*
 5.6 - 6.6(4)
<5.6 - 6.6**
```

Basically what I want to achieve is a match in the string of any of these options. Bearing in mind that I am passing in a variable which is something like (5.6 - 6.6) in this instance. Some of my values have "*" at the end and some don't so I need to test for when they do OR don't. But still need a match.

```
MY CODE WHICH WORKS ON "5.6 - 6.6*"

fieldValuesArray[0] = "5.6 - 6.6"

myregexp = new RegExp("\\b(<)?"+ fieldValuesArray[0]+"(\\*\\(\\)1234)?\\b")

testRegEx = myregexp.test("<5.6 - 6.6**")  
  if(testRegEx == false){
  hide = "yes"
}
```

It works when there is no "<" at the beggining but when there is one it wont find the value.

Hope someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

You must remember that the string you are checking for also has regex characters in it, i.e. the '.' character which means it will match any character so "5^6 - 6$6" would match so those need escaping (use as '.' to match a literal period).

To match your three examples the following will work:

```
.*?5\.6\s-\s6\.6(\*+|\(\d*\))
```

You can see there I've escaped the periods and specified white space rather than just spaces characters. This ensures that there is a white space character in your string rather that it being white space in your regex.